# Several knp menu templates in symfony 3

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

Is there a way to use several menu templates, instead of the one in vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views/knp_menu.html.twig

Or set template name right in Builder for certain menu (using the example in http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in knp_menu_render function we will call template AppBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig
then move demo menu file to src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Menu/knp_menu.html.twig like here in docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations

By steps:

In the template write:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu', 'template': 'AppBundle:Menu:knp_menu.html.twig'}) }}
```

copy file:

```
cp vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views/knp_menu.html.twig src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Menu/knp_menu.html.twig
```

Example of src/AppBundle/Menu/Builder.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;

class Builder implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Main', array('route' => 'homepage'));
        $menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav navbar-nav');

        // create another menu item
        $menu->addChild('About', array('route' => 'About'));
        $menu['About']->addChild('Contacts', array('route' => 'About'));
        $menu['About']->addChild('Contacts1', array('route' => 'About'));
        $menu['About']->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'dropdown-menu');
        // ... add more children

        return $menu;
    }
}
```